# jQuery mask plugin translation set default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I'm using [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) to mask a time input.

I've configured it like so:

```
$('#time').mask('99r00', {translation: { 'r': { pattern: /[\.,:]/ }}});
```

With this mask the user can input the following legal times:

```
21:00
21.00
21,00
,30
```

This almost works like I want it but there is one thing that I want to achieve for the user:

If the user inputs `2100` I want to mask it to `21:00`. So it needs to know the default character is `:`.
The mask doesn't know which character in the pattern he needs to put in there and disabled further typing.

So how to set a default character for the translation option?

Thanks.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cBhm/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified the plugin by adding a custom option to translation called `defaults`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/L4j8f/).

```
//getMasked: function
//... lines 298 - 302
else if (translation.defaults) {
    buf[addMethod](translation.defaults);
    m += offset;
    v -= offset;
}    
//...                                                                        

$('#timetrans').mask('99r00', {translation: { 
          'r': { pattern: /[:,\\.]/, defaults: ':'}}});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Need to wait some hours to reward the bounty.

Comment: This looks like a nice addition to [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/pulls). Can you make a pull-request? else I would like to do it with your permission.

Comment: @A1rPun I really don't mind you making a pull-request. :) It will take some time to add tests and such.

Comment: igorescobar [committed](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/commit/a2ac2155f316e169a43ae5ad8bbdc14f733c1fcf) it in release 1.8.0!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you want:

```
$('#time').mask('00:00');
```

It does all the replacements you need.

Comment: Please read my question and see fiddle.. Your solution does not accept dots and comma's.

Answer (score 0):

Guess, it was smth. with plugin version. I used latest and wrote fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4f5j/

```
$('#timetrans').mask('99D99', {'translation': {D: {pattern: /[\.,:]/}}});
```

Comment: Still have the same problem.. try typing 2100 in the field and it only  types 21.

Comment: Thanslation just means that . , : symbols are allowed

Comment: I know, I don't want to let the user type something that is a mask.

Comment: So, you should just leave `99:99`

Comment: How can the user input a dot or a comma when the mask is always a `:`?